# Query delta lake from Snowflake to read latest version

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, delta-lake

I want to load data from a Delta Table on Databricks into a table on Snowflake using the `MERGE INTO` command.

The goal is that the numbers of records that are at the Delta Table on Databricks look the same as the records at the table on Snowflake.

The problem that is happening is that Snowflake queries duplicate records due to the fact that Delta Lake(S3 path) has multiple versions.

What can I do to read only the latest version of the delta lake?

```
MERGE INTO myTable as target USING (
    SELECT
    $1:DAY::TEXT AS DAY,
    $1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY::TEXT AS CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
    $1:SOURCE::TEXT AS SOURCE,
    $1:PLATFORM::TEXT AS PLATFROM,
    $1:LOB::TEXT AS LOB
    FROM @StageFilePathDeltaLake
    (FILE_FORMAT => 'sf_parquet_format')
  ) as src 
        ON target.CHANNEL_CATEGORY = src.CHANNEL_CATEGORY 
        AND target.SOURCE = src.SOURCE 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
 DAY= src.DAY
,PLATFORM= src.PLATFORM
,LOB= src.LOB
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  (
      DAY,
      CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
      SOURCE,
      PLATFORM,
      LOB
) VALUES  (
  src.DAY,
  src.CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
  src.SOURCE,
  src.PLATFORM,
  src.LOB
);
```

The sf_parque_format was created with these details:

```
create or replace file format sf_parquet_format
    type = 'parquet'
    compression = auto;
```

Comment: Basically you'd need to use some kind of delta table driver to get the latest version AFAIK this should work if you push the data in from databricks (which has the most reliable delta table driver)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Do you know where can I get more info about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem above is that Snowflake is reading this as a Parquet file, and not as Delta.

The solution is easy, be explicit about its Delta nature: Create an external table using the above stage and `table_format = delta` and query from external table instead of querying directly from the stage.

```sql
create external table …
 location=@mystage/daily/
 refresh_on_create =  false
 auto_refresh = false
 file_format = (type = parquet)
 table_format = delta; -- this one
```

As an additional note from my teammates: If you want to see the latest data (after creating the external table if Delta Lake was updated), you will need to perform an `ALTER EXTERNAL TABLE {name} REFRESH`. Also you can create an insert only stream on top of the external table, but would only get populated after a REFRESH occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Snowflake now has native Delta Lake support for external tables:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#delta-lake-support
- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#external-table-that-references-files-in-a-delta-lake

Alternatively, you could also try this: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/snowflake-integration.html